# Speed of SELECT vs. SET in T-SQL

Tags: performance, t-sql

I've been led to believe that for single variable assignment in T-SQL, `set` is the best way to go about things, for two reasons:

- it's the ANSI standard for variable assignment
- it's actually faster than doing a SELECT (for a single variable)

So...

```
SELECT @thingy = 'turnip shaped'
```

becomes

```
SET @thingy  = 'turnip shaped'
```

But how fast, is *fast*? Am I ever really going to notice the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SET is faster on single runs. You can prove this easily enough. Whether or not it makes a difference is up to you, but I prefer SET, since I don't see the point of SELECT if all the code is doing is an assignment. I prefer to keep SELECT confined to SELECT statements from tables, views, etc.

Here is a sample script, with the number of runs set to 1:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @runs int
DECLARE @i int, @j int
SET @runs = 1
SET @i = 0
SET @j = 0

DECLARE @dtStartDate datetime, @dtEndDate datetime


WHILE @runs > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @j = 0
        SET @dtStartDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        WHILE @j < 1000000
            BEGIN
                SET @i = @j
                SET @j = @j + 1
            END
        SELECT @dtEndDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate) AS SET_MILLISECONDS


        SET @j = 0
        SET @dtStartDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        WHILE @j < 1000000
            BEGIN
                SELECT @i = @j
                SET @j = @j + 1
            END
        SELECT @dtEndDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate) AS SELECT_MILLISECONDS

        SET @runs = @runs - 1
    END
```

RESULTS:

Run #1:

SET_MILLISECONDS

5093

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5186

Run #2:

SET_MILLISECONDS

4876

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5466

Run #3:

SET_MILLISECONDS

4936

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5453

Run #4:

SET_MILLISECONDS

4920

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5250

Run #5:

SET_MILLISECONDS

4860

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5093

**Oddly, if you crank the number of runs up to say, 10, the SET begins to lag behind.**

Here is a 10-run result:

SET_MILLISECONDS

5140

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5266

SET_MILLISECONDS

5250

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5466

SET_MILLISECONDS

5220

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5280

SET_MILLISECONDS

5376

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5280

SET_MILLISECONDS

5233

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5453

SET_MILLISECONDS

5343

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5423

SET_MILLISECONDS

5360

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5156

SET_MILLISECONDS

5686

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5233

SET_MILLISECONDS

5436

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5500

SET_MILLISECONDS

5610

SELECT_MILLISECONDS

5266

Comment: nice, this is the kind of hard evidence I was looking for! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

I don't speed is an issue, it has to do with more with the assignment feature set. I came across [this](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/differences_between_set_and_select.htm) a while ago and there is something new in SQL Server 2008...I heard, try googling SQL Set vs Select SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: I think that's why we are here...to get answers.

Comment: How would you answer this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189610/speed-of-mulitple-variable-assignment-in-t-sql

Comment: I suspect you're kind of right, I think it might be down to one using less CPU time than the other but I'm not sure how to verify this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "execution plan", it should tell you the cost of each line of your statement

Comment: if you look at the execution plan for both of these, you'll see they both have a cost of zero

Comment: well thats basically your answer, the cost is negligible, so just stick with SET would be my advice