# What is the difference between SELECT and SET in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a stored proc that executes some dynamic sql. Here's the example I found on [4GuysFromRolla.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20210310160204/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/020600-1.shtml)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
  (@TableName varchar(255),
   @FirstName varchar(50),
   @LastName varchar(50))
AS

    -- Create a variable @SQLStatement
    DECLARE @SQLStatement varchar(255)

    -- Enter the dynamic SQL statement into the
    -- variable @SQLStatement
    SELECT @SQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM " +
                   @TableName + "WHERE FirstName = '"
                   + @FirstName + "' AND LastName = '"
                   + @LastName + "'"

    -- Execute the SQL statement
    EXEC(@SQLStatement)
```

If you notice, they are using the keyword **SELECT** intead of **SET**. I didn't know you could do this. Can someone explain to me the differences between the 2? I always thought **SELECT** was simply for selecting records.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866767/set-vs-select-whats-the-difference

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. The other question is asking about performance. I was asking about the keyword language difference

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SELECT is ANSI, SET @LocalVar is MS T-SQL

SELECT allows multiple assignents: eg SELECT @foo = 1, @bar = 2

Comment: Your first point is contradicted by many sources in @breitak67's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034634/what-is-the-difference-between-select-and-set-in-t-sql/1034756#1034756)

Comment: Damn! I'm getting old. However, the SELECT is also in ANSI now, I think.

Comment: Interesting that Sybase does not mention SET @var
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug598.htm

Answer (score 6):

Basically, SET is SQL ANSI standard for settings variables, SELECT is not.  SET works only for single assignments, SELECT can do multiple assignments.  Rather than write a long explanation that is well summarized in many places on the net:

[ryan farley blog](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/01/390.aspx)

[tony rogerson](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/05/18/449.aspx)

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189588/speed-of-select-vs-set-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Select allows multiple assignments.

***EDIT*** you beat me by 44 seconds

Answer (score 0):

SELECTs may be faster if you need to assign multiple values:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/01/25/defensive-database-programming-set-vs-select.aspx

Comment: Given you still have to write the values into memory, I doubt it. It's still 2 assignment whether it's 2xSET or 1xSELECT.

Comment: gbn, I provided benchmarks. you can run benchmarks and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

Select can also be used to get the variable assignment from a select statement (assuming the statement only returns one record)

Select @myvariable = myfield from my table where id = 1