# SELECT SQL Variable - should i avoid using this syntax and always use SET?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This may look like a duplicate to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034634/what-is-the-difference-between-select-and-set-in-t-sql), but it's not. I am trying to get a best practice, not a technical answer (which i already (think) i know).

New to SQL Server and trying to form good habits.
I found a great explanation of the functional differences between `SET @var =` and `SELECT @var =`
here:   http://vyaskn.tripod.com/differences_between_set_and_select.htm
To summarize what each has that the other hasn't (see source for examples):

SET:

1. ANSI and portable, recommended by Microsoft.
2. `SET @var = (SELECT column_name FROM table_name)` fails when the select returns more then one value, eliminating the possibility of unpredictable results.
3. `SET @var = (SELECT column_name FROM table_name)` will set `@var` to NULL if that's what `SELECT column_name FROM table_name` returned, thus never leaving `@var` at it's prior value.

SELECT:

1. Multiple variables can be set in one statement
2. Can return multiple system variables set by the prior DML statement
3. `SELECT @var = column_name FROM table_name` would set `@var` to (according to my testing) the last value returned by the select. This could be a feature or a bug. Behavior can be changed with `SELECT @j = (SELECT column_name FROM table_name)` syntax.
4. Speed. Setting *multiple* variables with a *single* SELECT statement as opposed to multiple SET/SELECT statements is *much* quicker. He has a sample test to prove his point. If you could design a test to prove the otherwise, bring it on!

So, what do i do?

- (Almost) always use `SET @var =`, using `SELECT @var =` is messy coding and not standard.

  OR
- Use `SELECT @var =` freely, it could accomplish more for me, unless the code is likely to be ported to another environment.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for a wellwritten question and for having searched the archives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my opinion - use SET for simple operations such as `SET @var = 'hardcoded_value'` and use SELECT for doing tricker assignments such as from a table. I almost always end up writing select into variable statements in the following way to make my intentions clear to both the compiler and any other developers: `SELECT TOP 1 @var = col_name FROM some_table`

If I was worried about portability I wouldn't be writing T-SQL and instead would stick with an ORM layer for data access instead.

Edit, bonus tip: In SQL 08 I like using this syntax which is fairly terse for T-SQL:

`DECLARE @var int = (SELECT col_name FROM some_table)`

Comment: I agree, stored procs are never going to port easily given that no database really supports the ANSI standard.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much left to say as the article you mention yourself already covers it nicely.

> Are standards important to you? If
>   your answer is 'yes', then you should
>   be using SET.

As for my own standards, I don't really use one over the other, it depends on the alignment of the planets. After reading the article, I must confess I have a slight preference for `SET`.

Comment: standards _are_ important, but i can't seem to get past the fact that SELECT allows me to set multiple variables in one go.

Comment: If that is what concerns you then don't worry and just use SELECT in this way. It gets the job done, believe me!