# Is there a performance difference on T-SQL SET syntax?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speed of SELECT vs. SET in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189588/speed-of-select-vs-set-in-t-sql)

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

When I use

```
DECLARE @out INT
```

Which is faster:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @out = myCol FROM myTable
```

or

```
SET @out = (SELECT TOP 1 myCol FROM myTable)
```

What if myCol is Primary key, Index or regular column?

---

Edit: (as for mark-schultheiss comment)

The thing is, I'm looking for the causes of delays.

for example:

3x `SET = (SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE)` is slower than 1 SELECT with 3 assignments like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @out1 = myCol1, @out2 = myCol2, @out3 = myCol3 
FROM myHugeTable WHERE myCol4 = 7
```

where myCol1 is the PK, the myCol2 is IX, myCol3 is a regular column, and myCol4 is non unique index

so, are there known issues causing delays which one can avoid?

Comment: @arran - This is partial, simplified and to specific. I'm looking for the cause of delays. What about 3 SETs or once SELECT on HUGE tables. for example: Which is faster, 3 SET+SELECTs OR `SELECT TOP 1 @out1 = myCol1, @out2 = myCol2, @out3 = myCol3 FROM myHugeTable WHERE myCol4 = 7` where myCol1 is the PK, the myCol2 is IX, myCol3 is a regular column, and myCol4 is non unique index. See, there can be to many examples to think of, therefore, I'm looking for the cause of delays.

Comment: @Different111222 Add those details to the question to make it more specific on your need here.  IF you have a very specific set of code at issue I would recommend that here also.

Comment: The easiest way to answer any "which is faster" question is to use a) execution plans in SSMS and b) SQL Profiler to see for yourself.